# SQL Server client-server app with user system

Tags: sql, sql-server

My project represents client-server app with server side wroten on stored procedures.
Procedures are looks like `addMsg`, `getMsgs` etc.

But i don't know how to implement user system. Currently, I have `users` table contains it's data like login, password and another data; and i comparing login and password inside procedures each time to grant access!

For example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE addMsg
@login text,
@pass text,
@msg text
AS
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM users WHERE login=@login AND pass=@pass) THEN
INSERT INTO messages...
END
GO
```

It is not right approach i think, so i interested if there are any another approaches to implement user system.

I have to associate with the user another data like First Name, Address etc., so SQL users are not suitable here.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What's wrong with this approach exactly?  Other than that your password should probably have some sort of encryption and that you should probably verify that `@login` and `@pass` aren't NULL or empty strings.

Comment: @nhgrif, ty, i just thought it was done somehow by another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your table definition should be something like below:-

### Table:-**User** with below column

Id,login,Pass,UserId,Lastlogin

### Table:-**Accounts** with below column

UserId,Name,Address,........

I would actually prefer to create separate procedure for user check such as below:-

create procedure UserCheck
@login text,
@pass text
as
begin
   select * from Users where login = @login and pass = @pass
end

And before adding message to the system,Call above UserCheck procedure to check whether record for given login and pass.If so,then call below procedure to actually add message.

create procedure addMsg
@msg text
as
begin
  insert into message....
end

Comment: I agree with you. Thanks!